# How to I identify the id's of opportunity fields other than the default ones so that I may fill these using a macro from Excel?

Tags: salesforce-id, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

So the nature of my work means that I need to keep a record of our opportunities on an excel spreadsheet, and then these are then to be transferred to Salesforce so that management have a clear picture of the business we have. Therefore I would like to create a macro to open the opportunity, and update the desired fields and save it.

I've sorted the opening of the page and have been able to update some fields, but these are just those that have default ids "opp3", "opp9" etc. My problem arises when I try to input a value to one of the fields that doesn't have this standard "oppxx" id.

My VBA code reads as follows:

```
    'Fills status box
    ie.document.all("opp11").Value = "Bound"
    'Fills Underwriter's name
    ie.document.all("Element_ID").Value = "Underwriter's Name"
```

It's the correct Element_ID which I cannot find. I've looked at the source code on IE9 but haven't been able to identify the correct ID. Copy of the source code is below just in case anyone can help point out what it is I need.

```
   </td><td class="labelCol"><label for="CF00N20000001bV1Y">Underwriter</label></td>
   <td class="dataCol">
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkid" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkid" value="003D000001OwQa8" />
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkold" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkold" value="Ed Gandon" />
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lktp" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lktp" value="003" />
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lspf" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lspf" value="0" />
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lspfsub" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lspfsub" value="0" />
   <input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_mod" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_mod" value="0" />
   <span class="lookupInput"><input  id="CF00N20000001bV1Y" 
    maxlength="255" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y" onchange="getElementByIdCS('CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS
    ('CF00N20000001bV1Y_mod').value='1';" size="20" tabindex="19" type="text" value="Ed Gandon" />
   <a href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui% 2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3DeditPage%26lknm%3DCF00N20000001bV1Y%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%
    27CF00N20000001bV1Y_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27CF00N20000001bV1Y%27%
    29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkwgt" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" tabindex="19" title="Underwriter Lookup 
    (New Window)">
   <img src="/s.gif" alt="Underwriter Lookup (New Window)"  class="lookupIcon" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" 
    onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className
```

I've tried using "CF00N20000001bV1Y" and any variation thereof "_mod", "_lkid" etc but none of them work in changing the value in the field I'm trying to change. Has anyone got any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

After formatting the code you supplied so that it was readable, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkold" id="CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkold" value="Ed Gandon" />
```

"CF00N20000001bV1Y_lkold" would appear to be the ID within the Form for the field you're looking for and "Ed Gandon" would be the value associated with it. Those aren't Salesforce Opportunity Ids (not the right number of chars - would either be 15 or 18), just parameters used to link the values with the form field labels for display at output time.